# Raspberry Pi crashes on boot

Tags: raspberry-pi-os

So I got a new Raspberry Pi. It turns on, is trying to boot from my SD-Card but crashes halfway through. I already tried to remove all accessories but it didn`t work.

Comment: To help you, we need a little bit  more information. What is your set-up (headless? with keyboard/screen?) How do you know it crashes? What do you see? Did you check the boot-problems issue on https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/? Is it possible to read the logs (`/var/log/messages`) of the sd-card, and if so, did you see any messages that may give a hint?

Comment: Which Pi version, and what's on the SD card?

Comment: What power supply?

Comment: @LjmDullaart It is already fixed just one boot into recovery mode made it

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev It is the 8gb version i imaged it with etcher but i skipped the validating stage

Comment: @CoderMike Just a standard 5v powebank

Comment: @maxipi i suggest you get this working with an official power supply before attempting to use a powerbank. I assume Pi4 8GB. Use https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/type-c-power-supply/

Comment: Why skip the Etcher validation stage?

Comment: @CoderMike it fixed itself

Comment: @maxipi how did it do that?

Comment: @CoderMike idk how it fixed it,